# Bulk product editing in wordpress

Tags: customization

I am trying to bulk edit products when I select several items and hit edit it loads the page but then closes itself like I never hit the edit button in the 1st place. Do you know why it wont stay on page so I can edit? –  Dan Berkoski 5 secs ago   edit

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be misunderstanding something (or not fully explaining something). If you click the "Edit" link under each post, it'll take you to the edit page for that post/page/whatever.

The bulk edit actions are the ones in the dropdown on the top bar. You need to select as many posts as you want, choose an option from the dropdown and then click on "apply".

There is no other "Edit" link I can think of.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response, when I try to bulk edit products which would be the same as posts for example I click 4-5 items or whole page of items of un-categorized products and hit edit to add categories to each item the items open for only seconds and closes back to original screen before I can do anything.

Comment: Now I catch the continued reference to "products" instead of "posts". Obviously you are using some kind of theme/plugin that adds that cpt, and there is something poorly defined there. Without access to the code it's impossible to know more.